# What encryption method does .NET use when setting secure="true" in a remoting channel configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

We have been asked by a customer which encryption methods are used for our remoting calls -- we use the `secure="true" tokenImpersonationLevel="impersonation"` attributes on the channel in the configuration file.

Is this using Kerberos?  NTML? CHAPS?

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

EDIT:  We use TCP channels for remoting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a secure TCP channel (suppoert starting with .NET 2) uses SSPI to encrypt the data.

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c10253

According to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface
The "Secure channel" is using differen encrpytions depending on the OS support, but SSL/TLS is part of it.

Comment: Thanks!  Is this regarded as esoteric knowledge, or was it easy to find out?

Comment: @Dr Herbie, sorry it got mixed up in my head, because of WCF probably which is different in this regard. However, I have found a description of what you were looking for, see the link. Sorry for the confusion.